# Proving the following set is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been trying to solve a question related to group theory. If we consider that the question says that $f^0$ is the identity and $f^0$ and $f$ is the same and just an error, then how identity $\times$ identity = another function.

I can easily prove that it is associative and maintains closure property using cayley table but I can't understand how $f^0$ is both an identity function as well as gives some other value when multiplied by itself.

[image]

Comment: $f^0$ is not $f$, it is the identity map from $X$ to $X$

Comment: Why do you say that $f^0$ gives another value when multiplied by itself?

Comment: What is the difference between identity and identity map. Also I considered f0=f

Comment: In this case the identity map is the identity of the group. If you consider $f^0$ to be $f$ then it is not the identity, the question doesn't do that.

Comment: What does f refer to then ?

Comment: $f=\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 3,4\rangle,\langle 4,1\rangle\}$, as in the question. Notation varies and your book / course should define this properly, but this probably means $f(1)=2,f(2)=3,f(3)=4,f(4)=1$.

Comment: I'm pretty weak in this topic.what does f o f refer to ? Mapping ?And what is f2 and the others

Comment: it's ok, $\circ$ is composition of maps, so if you have maps $h,g:X\to X$ then $(h\circ g)(x)=h(g(x))$. For brevity $f^n$ is $f$ composed with itself $n$ times, so $f^2=f\circ f$.

Comment: So how can we draw a cayley table of this and prove it as a group ? And how is f4 = f0

Comment: This is becoming more and more Convoluted for me , sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90197/discussion-between-robert-chamberlain-and-naman-sood).

Answer (score 1):

We define $f^2$ as being the same function as $f \circ f$, so

$f^2(x) = (f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x))$

And then we can extend the notation:

$f^3(x) = (f^2 \circ f)(x) = f(f(f(x))) \\
f^4(x) = (f^3 \circ f)(x) = f(f(f(f(x))))$

and so on. And it also makes sense to say that $f^1(x) = f(x)$.

But what about $f^0(x)$ ? Well, if $f^0$ exists then we want it to satisfy the following identity:

$f(x) = f^1(x) = (f^0 \circ f)(x) = f^0(f(x))$

So $f^0$ is the identity function i.e. $f^0(f(x))=f(x)$ and $f^0(x)=x$. And then if we compose $f^0$ with itself we have

$(f^0)^2(x)=(f^0 \circ f^0)(x) = f^0(f^0(x))) = f^0(x)$

so $f^0 \circ f^0 = f^0$. And also

$(f^0 \circ f^n)(x) = f^0(f^n(x)) = f^n(x)$

In your example, $f$ maps $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $3$, so $f^2(1)=f(f(1))=f(2)=3$. Similarly $f^2(2) = f(f(2)) = f(3) = 4$. Continuing like this, we have

$f^2=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(4,2)\}$

In the same way, you can work out what $f^3$ is, and eventually you will find that $f^4(x)=x$, so $f^4=f^0$.

You should now be able to show that $F$ with the operation of composition of functions satisfies all four properties of a group.

Comment: To prove closure and associative we can show that the elements resulting are from the set of f. What would be the inverse of this.

Comment: Once you know that $f^0$ is the identity for composition of functions and $f^4=f^0$ then you can re-write this as $f^3 \circ f = f^0$. What does this suggest should be the inverse of $f$ ?

Comment: f^3 yes. So we only need to find the inverse of f ?

Comment: You need to show that all four members of $F$ have an inverse. But you know that $f^0$ is its own inverse, and since $f^3$ is the inverse of $f$ then you also know that $f$ is the inverse of $f^3$. So you are almost there.

Comment: also , 1 last query, f and f1 are both the same ?

Comment: How would I show that this is isomorphic with an addition modulo 4 Z ( integer ) set

Comment: This is because $f(x)=f^1(x)=x+1 /pmod 4$, $f^2(x)=x+2 /pmod 4$ and so on.

Comment: Wait how did we write f1(x) as x+1 % 4, sorry if I can't grasp it but I got lost on this step. Isn't the function o used for f(f(x)) etc. like you did above

Comment: Just look at the values that $f^1$ (which is the same as $f$) takes. $f^1(1)=2$, $f^1(2)=3$, $f^1(3)=4=0 \pmod 4$, $f^1(4)=1$.